# oracle 10g float formatting

Tags: sql, database, types, oracle10g

I'm having a problem with a Float variable I want to insert a price of 2 digits after the decimal.
if I insert a price = 129.99 , on the table it shows the rounded up price. is there a formatting system that makes the number after the decimal show up?

[image]

[image]

```
INSERT INTO BUY (BUY_ID,BOOK_ID,USER_ID,BUYDATE,PRICE,Quantity) VALUES (4,981237421623,2,TO_DATE('2016-07-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),189.99,1)
```

Comment: What is the code that produces this table?  You're showing an `insert` for `buy_id` of 4 but the table doesn't display that row.  I'd assume that whatever is displaying the table is doing the rounding so you'd need to change that code.  Separately, if you have actually declared a `price` as a `float`, that is almost certainly a mistake.  You almost certainly want a fixed precision number (i.e. `number(7,2)` assuming that no book is ever going to have a price of more than 99,999.99).

Comment: Floating point numbers are inherently imprecise which is a very bad property for a money value (https://husobee.github.io/money/float/2016/09/23/never-use-floats-for-currency.html)

Comment: Screenshot you posted looks like rather old Oracle Apex application (3.x or so, perhaps?). In that case, go to PRICE column's properties and set its format mask to e.g. `999G990D00`